# How can I rate convergence speed at infinity?

Tags: calculus

For example, I want to know how $1-e^{-x}$ converges to zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Can I rate the convergence speed at infinite (or approximation error) as in big-O notation in infinitesimal, such like $O(\frac{1}{x})$ or something? The taylor series $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ is not differentiable at zero, in above case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for rate of convergence of $1-e^{-1/x}$ here is the answer:

$e^{x}=\sum \frac {x^{n}} {n!}$ for every real number $x$. Hence $e^{-1/x} =1-\frac 1  x+\frac 1 {2x^{2}}...$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $1-e^{-1/x}=O(\frac 1 x)$.